# SAP process session txt no taking input column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sap

We have an Excel VBA that generates a .txt in order to make postings faster.

However, there is field that is not taking the field even if it is generated in the .txt:

[image]

As you can see, when checking in SAP how it is doing with the .txt we can see it is in blank (see in yellow below):

[image]

Do you have any ideas why it is leaving in blank? Maybe field name is wrong?

The main thing I see is that if I check field properties for "Product" (technical properties by pressing F1): Field Name is: ARTNR.
In my txt we have COBL-WERKS. That was my first attempt -> Change name in txt to COBL-ARTNR but is not working neither.

If I check a correct one, Profit center for example, I can see in txt is COBL-PRCTR and in technical information in SAP is also PRCTR.

That is why I am confusing.

Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Thank you all and best regards, Alfonso

Comment: You don't explain how the text file is used so that to inject data into screens? If it's **batch input** (transaction code `SHDB`), then you can run it screen by screen and you will see when the actual screens stop matching what you inject via this text file. The text file must absolutely match actual sequence of screens. It can be very difficult to know in advance what screens SAP will choose to display based on user input, customizing, transaction data, etc. If possible, instead of batch input, you could use SAP GUI Scripting which allows to take decisions during the run time.

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi, thank you for your advice! we are processing the txt with SM35 and executing in Process/foreground to see what data have been transfered. Everything looks good except [Product] field

Comment: @SandraRossi the problem I see is that if I check field properties for "Product" (technical properties by pressing F1): Field Name is: ARTNR. In my txt we have COBL-WERKS. That was my first attempt -> Change name in txt to COBL-ARTNR but is not working neither.

If I check a correct one, Profit center for example, I can see in txt is COBL-PRCTR and in technical information in SAP is also PRCTR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed in the macro that generates the txt to use:

RKEAK-FIELD(08) instead of COBL-WERKS and in screen SAPLKEAK0300X

Now it is working!